# Cell value change with Month

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to have certain dates out of the week from day 1 to the last day of the month when I type a month in a cell for example:

If cell "I6" Contains "March" or whatever month:

```
                      " MARCH "
```

then:

- cell "F10" = 1-Mar  for- **Sun** (first Sunday of the month)
- Cell "F11" = 5-Mar  for -Thur (First Thursday of the month)
- Cell "F12" = 8-Mar  for -**Sun** (second Sunday of the the month and so on)
- Cell "F13" =12-Mar  for -Thur

Is this possible? I have look in different sites but no luck
many thanks.

Comment: If what you show is exactly what you want in the cell, with the **Sun** bolded amongst other text, you will need a VBA solution.

Comment: The Sun being bolded was to point out that I need only Sundays and Thursdays from any given month. How can I add an image? I'm trying but not able to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may use this also:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- In Cell `K23`, enter 1st Date of the Month (like I've used `02/01/2020`, format is, `MM/DD/YYYY` ).
- Apply `MMM YY` to the Cell.
- Formula in cell `K25`:

`=K$23+MOD(7-WEEKDAY(K$23,2),7)`

- Next, formula in Cell `K26`:

`=K$23+MOD(4-WEEKDAY(K$23,2),7)`

**N.B.:** In above formula `7` & `4` represents Sunday and Thursday, and you may edit then as your need.

- Final formula in Cell `K27` & fill it down:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH(K26)=MONTH(K$23),COUNT(J$25:J25)=7),"",K25+7),"")
  ```
- Now enter this formula in Cell `J25` & fill down.

`=IF(ISBLANK(K25),"",K25)`

---

**Edited:**

OP has raised a good point that how to manage dates if and when **S**unday & **T**hursday are more than 8 (*like in May, August Sundays are 5 and Thursdays are 4*).

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `L25`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(N(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(K25&":"&EOMONTH(K25,0))),"ddd")="Sun"))+SUMPRODUCT(N(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(K25&":"&EOMONTH(K25,0))),"ddd")="Thu"))
  ```

**N.B.** *This Counts Sundays & Thursdays, 
         where `Sun` and `Thu` are 
         editable.*

- Formula in `K27`:

`=K$25+MOD(7-WEEKDAY(K$25,2),7)`

- Formula in Cell `k28`:

`=K$25+MOD(4-WEEKDAY(K$25,2),7)`

- Enter formula in Cell `K29`:

  ```
    =IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH(K28)=MONTH(K$25),COUNT(J$27:J27)>=(L$25-1)),"",K27+7),"")
  ```

---

**N.B.**

- *Use of MONTH check & ROW COUNT with formula in Cell `K27` & `K29`, restricts Excel to produce only DATEs for all Sundays & Thursdays.*
- *Now keep changing Date & Year in cell `K23` or in `K25` as needed.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Rajesh, your formula works flowlesly, dates will change accordingly in Column K (02/02/2020). On the other hand I'm getthing on Column J, " Sunday, March 1, 2020 " but its ok,  as far as I get the date for Sunday and Thursday. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Hey @PanchoVilla glad to help you keep asking ☺,, now you may accept this as ANSWER as well Up Vote also ! just [Check this](https://superuser.com/tour) .

Comment: Hi @Rajesh S, after working with my sheet, I noticed that I get no data with months that have more than 29 days? For example March, April, May etc, in the picture I have August, notice that it stops at Thursday 27th and its missing Sunday 30th. Same for the months past 29 days? [![Capture.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/xTVFsTXw/Capture.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/14MHXScB) Is excel stopping at a certain date number for the months?

Comment: @PanchoVilla,, now check the edited part,, I've posted the solution,, now you need to adjust formula as DATE & YEAR,, hope this help you ☺

Comment: thanks again... it worked as expected. You saved me for a lot of typing and time. Many thanks.

Comment: @PanchoVilla,, ☺ keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

So you can break this problem down into two parts:

**Conditional Formatting**

You want:

`cell "F10" = 1-Mar for- Sun (first Sunday of the month)`

based on `A6` containing `MARCH`

Therefore in cell F10 you can place

`=IFERROR(IF(FIND("MARCH",A6)<>0,"contains March","Does not contain march","")`

`=Find("MARCH",A6)` will error if it can't find "MARCH" which is why we use the `=IFERROR()`. If there is no error that means that it was successfully found and then apply the logic you want.

**First Sunday of the Month**

In order to find the first Sunday of a Month you can use this formula:

'=(A4+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A4,1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1))'

where A4 in my case is the date it is referencing then it will find forward, the next Sunday. If you plug in this method to the first you should be able to come up with what you want.

As far as cells A11, A12, A13 you can follow the same exact method.

Comment: When using the formula =IFERROR... I get ( You've entered too many arguments for this function.

Comment: IFERROR needs only two parameters. The first being the code to run if not an error, second if an error. In my example I put "" as what to show if an error

Comment: [![excel.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/ZnfsHZxm/excel.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/dZy9QbfN)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
F10:  =DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))+7-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))-1)
F11:  =DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))+7-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))-5)
F12:  =F10+7
```

Select `F12` and fill down as far as needed

```
G10: =F10
```

Custom format `G10` : `"dddd"`

Select `G10` and fill down as far as needed

[image]

**NOTE:** In some months, the first Thursday will occur before the first Sunday.  If you prefer to start with the earlier of the First Thu or First Sun, and then continue the sequence, then use these formulas:

```
    F10:=MIN(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))+7-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))-1),
DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))+7-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))-5))

    F11: =MAX(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))+7-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))-1),
DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))+7-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/"&I6 & "/" & YEAR(TODAY()))-5))
```

Comment: Ron, just to clarify...since I was giving an example using f10 and f11, using your formula I will have to change cells because my original sheet differs from whats on your formula. I will create one that matches f10 and f11 eventually and I will post results. I thanked you in advance.

Comment: @PanchoVilla I picked those cells based on the references you provided in your question. Obviously, if they are not correct, you will need to modify them. But `F10` only refers to where you put the formula.  And `G10` needs to be the cell one to the right.  The only cell reference in the formula is `I6` which refers to the month, which you indicated you typed in manually as a text string.